# ATM withdrawing money with highest bills 100s, 50s, 20s and 10s

Tags: c#

The task is to make a windows forms in vb.net where you input an amount of money and it will print out that amount in the highest possible bills. If possible i want it to all be one click and it shows all of the bills printed and the amounts.

But i am stuck on the 10s bills where it simply doesnt even calculate it. For instance when i input 870 it works but when i input 860 it doesnt.

Code is translated from vb.net to C#.

````
public partial class Form1
{
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int withdraw;
        withdraw = Val(TextBox1.Text);
        int bill_100;
        int bill_50;
        int bill_20;
        int bill_10;
        if (withdraw >= 100)
        {
            bill_100 = (int)(withdraw / 100d);
            withdraw = withdraw % 100;
            MsgBox("Here is " + bill_100 + " bills of 100KM");
            if (withdraw >= 50)
            {
                bill_50 = (int)(withdraw / 50d);
                withdraw = withdraw % 50;
                MsgBox("Here is " + bill_50 + " bills of 50KM");
                if (withdraw >= 20 && withdraw < 50)
                {
                    bill_20 = (int)(withdraw / 20d);
                    withdraw = withdraw % 20;
                    MsgBox("Here is " + bill_20 + " bills of 20KM");
                    if (withdraw >= 10 && withdraw < 20)
                    {
                        bill_10 = (int)(withdraw / 10d);
                        withdraw = withdraw % 10;
                        MsgBox(" Here is:" + bill_10 + " bills of 10KM");

                        // MsgBox("Here is " & bill_100 - 1 & " Bills of 100KM" & " Here is " & bill_50 & " bills of 50KM" & " Here is " & bill_20 & " Bills of 20KM" & " Here is " & bill_10 & " bills of10KM")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Do not nest your If's

Comment: Why do you post in C# when your Code is VB? That doesn't always behave the same, better stick to original.

Comment: To make it easier for yourself (and more readable in general); keep tally of a variable `leftToWithdraw`

Comment: @Fildor reason being is there is a lot more people who could comment on C# and propose changes on how i should do it and i would just convert the code to vb.net. But i understand your point.

Comment: Ok One way is to remove those hard code value in the if and all the if. Have a List of available bills note. And order them descending. The a simple loop will cover all the bills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will remove all the if and hard coded bill notes.
We have a list of avaidable bills note.

```
var availalbleBills = new[] { 100, 50, 20, 10 };
```

NB: we should order that list to be sure that we have them in the right order.

We could use the indice of those element to store the number bills given.
Or change the list to a more complexe structure. Like a dictionary with bills note as key and nomber of bills given as value.

Then we can simply loop on the array of bills. If the amount left is more that the bill value we should give a bill and remove it's value from the remaing.

```
var given = new []{0,0,0,0};
for(int i =0; i< availalbleBills.Count;i++ ) {
    var bill = availalbleBills[i];
    while (input >= bill) { 
        input -= bill;
        given[i] += 1;
    }
}
```

[live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QAX84n)

Comment: I used a simple while loop instead of the proper math because I find it more natural. It's the way you will do if you work as a cashier. You don't do division , you do 20+20+20 till you have less than 20. Your math was the correct way. But changing the whole thing I thougt i should make it simple

Comment: Displaying given(i) it shows the correct amount of 100s bills, but then it fails showing 50s 20s and 10s if i input a number with that kind of value.

Comment: Are you trying to display the after the while loop?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine( $"Here is {given[i]} bills of {availalbleBills[i]}KM");` Should work just after the while loop, and before the end of the for loop.

Comment: `For i As Integer = 0 To availalbleBills.Count - 1
            Dim bill = availalbleBills(i)

            While input >= bill
                input -= bill
                given(i) += 1

            End While
            MsgBox("Here is " & given(i) & " Bills of 100KM")
        Next`


Your code does work fine, its just trying to display it properly now. 
It displays the correct amounts but it is always ending with " Bills of 100km" and i need to figure out how to make it show "bills of 50km" when i click ok on msgBox.

Comment: `"100KM""`, the array store the bill notes value. The 100 should not be hard coded. The variable `bill` is equals to 100,50,20..

Comment: I thou having a variable for the number 100,50 was clearer. We even used it twice. ^^

Comment: That was the clue i needed so thanks :)

`MsgBox("Here is " & given(i) & " Bills of " & bill & "KM")` 

Now it works properly. Do you think is there any way all of the resulting bills could be displayed in only one popup msgBox or Console.WriteLine..... for instance:

MsgBox(Amount 100s bills, Amount 50s bills...etc )?

Comment: Yes you already have those information in both array. Either concatenate your result instead of diplaying them. and display at the end of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] Withdraw(int amount){
        var bank = new int[] { 100, 50, 20 };
        var list = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        var money = amount;
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (money == 0) break;

            var b = (int)Math.Floor((double)money / bank[i]);
            if (b > 0)
            {
                list[i] = b;
                money -= b * bank[i];
            }
            else if (money < bank[i])
            {
                if (list[i] == 0)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        if (list[i - 1] > 0)
                        {
                            list[i - 1] -= 1;
                            money += bank[i - 1];
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    list[i] -= 1;
            }
            i++;
            if (i > bank.Length) break;
        }
        return list;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are like locks in a puzzle game deciding which notes to give the user.

Unfortunately, the way your puzzle is set up, some of the notes will never be reached.

Here is an example:

---

If I only want to withdraw a 10 bill, your system will never be able to provide it to me.

The reason for that is that a 10 bill is less than a 100 bill but with your current implementation I will first have to ask to withdraw a 100 bill, a 50 bill, and a 20 bill in addition to the 10_bill totaling at 180.

---

When an if statement "A" is nested in another if statement "B"

```
if (B) {
   if (A) {
      "some information"
   }
}
```

It is equivalent to having a single if statement with a condition of (A and B)

```
if ( B AND A ) {

}
```

That is that the condition of B needs to be true, if that conditional is true then look at the condition of A, If the conditional of A is also true then I have "some information"

Try removing what we call nested if statements and make sure that when you read the code with the "if x is true then do what is inside the {}" hat on, that the program still makes sense.

Comment: If you feel that I explained the reason why your code did not function as you expected it helped you, could you please mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use something like this:

```
 int withdraw;
        withdraw =  Val(TextBox1.Text);
        int bill_100;
        int bill_50;
        int bill_20;
        int bill_10;
        bool calculate = true;

        while (calculate)
        {
            if (withdraw >= 100)
            {
                bill_100 = (int)(withdraw / 100d);
                withdraw = withdraw % 100;
                MsgBox("Here is " + bill_100 + " bills of 100KM");
               
            }
            if (withdraw >= 50)
            {
                bill_50 = (int)(withdraw / 50d);
                withdraw = withdraw % 50;
                MsgBox("Here is " + bill_50 + " bills of 50KM");
                
            }
            if (withdraw >= 20 && withdraw < 50)
            {
                bill_20 = (int)(withdraw / 20d);
                withdraw = withdraw % 20;
                MsgBox("Here is " + bill_20 + " bills of 20KM");
               
            }

            if (withdraw >= 10 && withdraw < 20)
            {
                bill_10 = (int)(withdraw / 10d);
                withdraw = withdraw % 10;
                MsgBox(" Here is:" + bill_10 + " bills of 10KM");

                // MsgBox("Here is " & bill_100 - 1 & " Bills of 100KM" & " Here is " & bill_50 & " bills of 50KM" & " Here is " & bill_20 & " Bills of 20KM" & " Here is " & bill_10 & " bills of10KM")
            }
            else
            {
                calculate = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is better about this and why do you think so?

Comment: Because his code missed some value(for nested if) and with this code can cover value under 10

Comment: A good answer would explain this, since it is obviously not obvious to the OP ;)

Comment: You don't need a while, because you only loop once. you don't need the checks "withdraw < ..." because it is always smaller

Comment: Would appreciate a good answer to understand this properly @Fildor saeed-esmaeelinejad